# Flash record and play plays 2x faster

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I am making simple AS3 application that will record audio from microphone and after that play it using ByteArray data.

I made application, it's recording, but when I try to play it it's playing 2x faster...

Interesting thing is that it was okay before, and now it's faster... And even when I run old file, that have code that was 100% working before it's also faster now...

Here is code:

```
import flash.media.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var ch:SoundChannel;
var soundBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var soundO:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var sound:Sound= new Sound();


var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
var recMode:Boolean = false;
var playMode:Boolean = false;

function init()
{
    mic.codec = "Speex";
    mic.setSilenceLevel(0);
    mic.gain = 50;
    mic.rate = 44;
}

function startRecord():void
{
    mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
}
function stopRecord():void
{
    mic.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
    soundBytes.position = 0;
    soundO.length = 0;
    soundO.writeBytes(soundBytes);
    soundO.position = 0;
    soundBytes.length = 0;
}

function micSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    while (event.data.bytesAvailable)
    {
        var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();
        soundBytes.writeFloat(sample);
    }
}

function playSound():void
{
    soundO.position = 0;
    sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
    ch = sound.play();
    ch.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,onSC);
}
function stopSound():void
{
    sound.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
    ch.stop();
    ch.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,onSC);
}
function onSC(evt:Event):void
{
    stopSound();
    soundO.position = 0;
    playMode = ! true;
    rec_btn.visible = true;
    rec_btn2.visible = false;
    play_btn.visible = true;
    play_btn2.visible = false;
}
function playbackSampleHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
    {
        if (soundO.bytesAvailable < 4)
        {
            break;
        }
        var sample:Number = soundO.readFloat();
        event.data.writeFloat(sample);
        event.data.writeFloat(sample);


    }
}

rec_btn.buttonMode = rec_btn2.buttonMode = play_btn.buttonMode = play_btn2.buttonMode = true;
function showPlayUI()
{
    play_btn.visible = true;
}
function hidePlayUI()
{
    play_btn2.visible = false;
    rec_btn2.visible = false;
}
rec_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onRecord);
rec_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onRecord);
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPlay);
play_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPlay);


function onRecord(evt:MouseEvent=null):void
{
    if (playMode)
    {
        playMode = ! true;
        play_btn2.visible = false;
        play_btn.visible = true;
        stopSound();
    }


    if (! recMode)
    {
        recMode = true;
        rec_btn.visible = false;
        rec_btn2.visible = true;
        play_btn2.visible = false;
        startRecord();
    }
    else
    {
        recMode = ! true;
        rec_btn.visible = true;
        rec_btn2.visible = false;
        play_btn2.visible = false;
        stopRecord();
        showPlayUI();
    }
}
function onPlay(evt:MouseEvent=null):void
{
    if (recMode)
    {
        recMode = false;
        rec_btn.visible = true;
        rec_btn2.visible = false;
        stopRecord();
    }

    if (! playMode)
    {
        playMode = true;
        rec_btn2.visible = false;
        play_btn2.visible = true;
        play_btn.visible = false;
        playSound();
    }
    else
    {
        playMode = ! true;
        rec_btn2.visible = false;
        play_btn2.visible = false;
        play_btn.visible = true;
        stopSound();
    }
}


hidePlayUI();
init();
```

As you can see encode rate is 44, which is accept rate...

I tested this on Vista and on XP on my PC, and on both it's faster...

Here is the URL:
[Record and Play](http://tinyurl.com/flashmic)

Comment: It's because Speex codec isn't playing correctly... When I remove that line it's playing normally...

Comment: Hi could you give me a link to download the source of  http://tinyurl.com/flashmic ? 
I am less than a beginner in flash and I can't playback at normal speed... I saw your link and it's working now, you can playback at normal speed. 
Right now I have the code to convert a record to mp3, but I don't know how to playback the recording at normal speed. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Speex codec, since it's encoding microphone differently, so when you try to use it's levels as Float it's writing it as **encoded** sound, not as original...

Double lines are okay, it should be that way...

ByteArray is not working okay with Speex codec, use default codec instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not call this twice in your playbackSampleHandler.

```
    event.data.writeFloat(sample);
    event.data.writeFloat(sample);
```

Comment: No, no, it should be that way... I tried to remove that and then it goes 4x faster, so that is not the problem... and also it was working before with both lines... It's for both channels, levels of sound for left and right speaker, so it must come in pair...

Comment: Also, I sent a link at bottom, can you test it and tell me is it playing in regular speed for you? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is plays fast here (btw nice unwanted feature).

Comment: @SharkTheDark so was double `event.data.writeFloat(sample);` statement the cause of the problem? because you initially said it wasn't, "No, no, it should be that way... I tried to remove that and then it goes 4x faster, so that is not the proble"...

Comment: No, problem was in Speex codec, since it's encoding microphone differently, so when you try to use it as Float it's writing it as encoded sound, not as original... double lines are okay, it should be that way...